# A question of an autonomous ODE defined in the interior of a compact set such as a simplex.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Denote $S := \{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \| x \|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1, x_i \geq 0, \ \forall i = 1,...,n \}$, $\text{int} S$ as it's interior (points with stricly positive coordinates) $\partial S$ as it's boundary (points with some zeros). We would like to investigate the solution of an autonomous equation

$$ \dot x_t = f(x_t), \quad x_0 = a \in \text{int} S, \ I =[0,\infty) $$

where $f: \text{int} S \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is a continuously differentiable function of a special form: if $f =(f_1,...,f_n)$ then $\sum f_i = 0$, $f$ explodes at $\partial S$. Suppose the maximal interval of existence is $[0,T)$, can this solution be extended to $[0,T]$?

What I know from the ODE theory is that there are some conditions for this extension to be possible for some open domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. For example the function $g(t) = \sin (\frac{3}{t-2})$ cannot be extended to $[0,2]$. However in this case, we are working with a simplex in $\mathbb R^n$ which is a subset of a plane. This question arises when I was trying to prove that the solution on the interior of the simplex exists on $[0,\infty)$. I was trying to prove that the solution exists only inside a compact subset of $S$ thus exists for all times but I failed with this strategy.

I'm thinking that the existence of such a solution on the simplex can be equivalently thought as an "extension" solution of

$$ \dot y_t = f_r(y_t), \ y_0 = a_r \in O$$

where $f_r$ is the restrict of $f$ to $n-1$ dimension, i.e, if $f = (f_1,...,f_n)$ then $f_r = (f_1,...,f_{n-1})$; $O= \{x \in \mathbb R^{n-1}: \sum x_i  \in (0,1), x_i>0 \}$ is the domain of $f_r$. Because we can define $y_n = 1 - y_1 -...-y_n$ then $x=(y_1,...,y_n)$ is a solution of the original problem (on some maximal interval of existence).